# Google URLShortener with AccountManager and OAuth2: 401 unauthorized

Tags: android, oauth

I am trying to access the goo.gl URLShortener via API on Android. I am using the AccountManager to generate an access token:

```
String authTokenType = "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/urlshortener";
String authToken = this.prefs.getString(Key.PREF_GOOGLE_ACCESS_TOKEN, "null");
if (!"null".equals(authToken)) {
  accountManager.invalidateAuthToken(authTokenType, authToken);
}
//(...)
accountManager.getAuthToken(account, authTokenType, false, new GetAuthTokenCallback(), null);
```

When I run the HTTP Request in the `GetAuthTokenCallback` with the generated auth token to receive the URL history I get the status `401:unauthorized`:

```
HttpGet http_get = new HttpGet("https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url/history");
http_get.addHeader("Authorization", tokens[0]);

HttpResponse response;
response = GoogleOAuthOnPreferenceChangeListener.this.http_client.execute(http_get);
Log.d("tag", "Status: (" + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() + ") " + response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
```

The Content of the JSON-Response is

```
{ 
  "error": {
    "errors": [
       {
         "domain": "global",
         "reason": "required",
         "message": "Login Required",
         "locationType": "header",
         "location": "Authorization"
       }
     ],
     "code": 401,
     "message": "Login Required"
   }
}
```

I Have

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ForDevices#callinganapi, you should set the header to

```
Authorization: Bearer <access_token>
```

Instead of

```
Authorization: <access_token>
```